# How to set the local user account photo with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to set the local account photo using PowerShell and an image saved in a certain location.

the same as if you go to:
Settings >> Accounts >> Your Info >> Create your picture >> Browse for one >> Go to "C:\custom-folder\img.jpg" >> select "okay"

Here is the script I am working on:

```
$registryPath = "HKCU:\ ? "
$nameAttr = " ? "
$imgPath = "C:\custom-folder\img.jpg"

Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $nameAttr -Value $imgPath
Write-Host "Account photo has been set."
```

Don't know what to put for the question marks?

Comment: This is not a powershell or programming question. It is more suitable for a site like superuser.com as you're trying to find what to set, not how to set it.

Comment: okay, thanks, I'll move it over there.

Comment: link to same question on superuser.com : https://superuser.com/questions/1687011/how-to-set-the-local-user-account-photo-with-powershell-the-image-that-shows-up